# ACF not displaying the value in the footer of the wp theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This seems really simple, but I can't get it to work.  All I want is to display a heading that is stored as a custom field (it's the h3 tag).  I'm using it another place in my code and it works, but not in the footer.  Do ACF only work in some areas and not others?

```
<footer class="section section--footer">
    <div class="section--footer__header">
$post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        <h3 class="text-white"><?php echo the_field("cta_field_title",$post_id);?></h3>
    </div>
    <form action="#" class="section--footer__form">
        <div class="section--footer__input-box center">
            <label for="name"></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name" class="input">
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="email address" class="input">
        </div>
        <div class="button__box center">
            <a href="#" class="button">Submit</a>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="section--footer__links">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            "theme_location" => "footer",
            "menu" => "desktop",
            "menu_class" => "section--footer__links"
        )) ?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            "theme_location" => "social",
            "menu" => "desktop",
        )) ?>
    </div>

</footer>

<?php wp_footer() ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using ACF functions to get the field value outside the Wordpress "loop", you need to pass the post id into the function as the 2nd argument, e.g.

```
$post_id = get_queried_object_id(); // gets the id of the current page/post
the_field("cta_field_title", $post_id);
```

(FYI, you don't need to use echo with `the_field`... the function displays the value already. However you do need to use it with `get_field`, `get_fields` etc).

So your footer will look something like this:

```
<footer class="section section--footer">
    <div class="section--footer__header">
        <?php $post_id = get_queried_object_id();  /* get the current page/post id */ ?>
        <h3 class="text-white"><?php the_field("cta_field_title", $post_id);?></h3>
    </div>
    // rest of your code here
</footer>
```

References:

- [Documentation for ACF `the_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)
- [Codex for the Wordpress Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much.  I'm just curious why it works in some places in not others.  I use 'echo get_field("field name") in other spots and it works fine.

Comment: Glad to help! You need to be inside the [**Wordpress "loop"**](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) for it to work without the post id. The loop is the code between `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` and your `endwhile; endif;` It sets up the post information so it can be accessed without the post id. Outside of this, the loop-specific function like `the_title`, `the_content` etc don't work. (In reality its a bit more complicated then that, as they can also work if the global `$post` variable is set up elsewhere, but that's the basic idea!)

Comment: So, now I'm calling my footer (get_footer()) in other page templates, and the field is not showing up again!  I've tried adding the loop and also the $post_id, but it still won't show.  Any ideas?

Comment: @jpaulMolnar No, don't add the loop to your footer! You just need to get the post id and pass it into `the_field`. Are you using `get_queried_object_id` like in the code above and is it not getting the post id?

Comment: Yep, I'm using the post_id variable and it seems to be working for the home page. But when I call the footer in template pages it's not showing up.

Comment: @jpaulMolnar Have you tried printout out the value in `$post_id` to make sure it is right? Is this in the same footer template that is being included on your homepage, and is it using the code above? Because the code your new question doesn't include the post_id at all, which won't work most of the time.

Comment: Yes it's the same footer template.  I've replaced the if/while loop with the $post_id.

Comment: Well then you need to update the code in that question to show the code you are using, otherwise people help to you are working on the wrong code! Show the exact footer code that is working in your homepage footer and is not working in the other pages that is not. And did you printout the value of the post id to check it? Add this just after `<div class="section--footer__header">`in the footer: `<?php echo "<h1>POST ID=".$post_id."</h1>"; ?> ` and tell me what shows in the footer of your homepage and the footer of the page its not working in.

Comment: Sorry!  I misunderstood.  Yes, that is the original code in my footer template.  I've just updated it to include the $post_id.

Comment: It gives me the id 141.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216985/discussion-between-fluffykitten-and-jpaulmolnar).